# html login form not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

This is the code I have for a simple login form in one of my WordPress page. It's supposed to redirect you to a page called `authenticate`, but it fails to do so and only goes to a blank page. I have tried changing the action to  `/authenticate.php` , `authenticate` , `authenticate.php` and none of them work.  How can I fix this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<!-- [banner] -->
<header id="banner">
    <hgroup>
        <h1>Test Login</h1>
    </hgroup>       
</header>
<!-- [content] -->
<section id="content">
    <form id="login" action="authenticate" method="post">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" required>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" required>                  
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</section>
<!-- [/content] -->

</div>
<!-- [/page] -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you sending form data? Do you have any php file OR wordpress function which handle form data? Why you want to use custom login form instead of wordpress login form?

Comment: The purpose of this form in not like the custom login, the purpose is to allow users to login and access content from the database eventually. I am doing this in the Visual Editor in wordpress.

Comment: what type of content access you wanna provide?

Comment: some download links to pdfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create custom login page because you can utilize wordpress login page.

**Here are the steps:** to allow registeration

1. **Login** to Dashboard
2. **Go To** Settings > General
3. **Check** Anyone can register
4. Save

Now visitor can create account and login on your site. (Don't forget to create login and registration page in menu so it is accessible to visitors.)

As above method will have default wordpress login/registration page so If you want to **customize** those pages then I would recommend this plugin. [User registration & user profile – Profile Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/)

And for controlling who can access your PDFs, try this plugin. [Download Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a full WordPress path:

```
<form id="login" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/authenticate' ) ); ?>"> 
...
</form>
```

Do make sure you have proper template setup and permalink setup before submitting your form authenticate page.

- Check out this page for more on [WordPress templating](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)
- If you want to use WordPress login functionality then check this
  [Function reference to wp login form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form)

Comment: can I add the Wordpress path in the Visual editor? @Tamal Dey